# I need a little help implementing player movement on java grid

Tags: java, user-interface

I need a little help with java, I am new to the language hence I have no idea on how to implement such.

I have already made a basic 15;40 grid JLabel Image, thanks to this site as well, what I need help with is about how to make a player(Supposed to be an Image, also shown on the grid) move around using either WASD(I don't know if Ascii-approach works on java) or Arrow Keys.

Here's my code for the Grid

```
public class GUI {
    static Scanner cns = new Scanner(System.in);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon ImageIcon = new ImageIcon("Grass.png");
    JLabel[][] grid;

    public GUI(int width, int length) {
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length));
        grid = new JLabel[width][length];

        for(int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                grid[x][y] = new JLabel();
                grid[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                grid[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());   
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pane.add(grid[x][y]= new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Grass.png")));
                grid[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                grid[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                frame.add(grid[x][y]);
           }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI(15, 40);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Scanners, I suggest you use KeyListeners. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: I did try using KeyListener. but my player won't even show... D:

Comment: Ok I'll post an answer soon and I'll add an indepth example when I get home...

Comment: Advice and tips would help a lot too. Since I think I'll be dealing more with java this coming summer. ugh. college. also, thank you so much for a quick response.

Comment: Yeah I'll write a complete example... For now I just realized how sketchy it is :)

Comment: I got it :)
Take a look at the example, comment if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of suggestions here:

1 - Make GUI extend JFrame and implement KeyListener.

You have to override KeyListener methods (keyPressed, keyReleased, and keyTyped) and you should override repaint() from JFrame.

The repaint method should call super.repaint() at the end to update frames.

2 - Have the fields of GUI store data about the things that need to be drawn.

You probably should store the grid, or what's in the grid as fields.

3 - The constructor should initialize, not render.

Rendering should be done in repaint(). The constructor should do something like this:

```
    super();
    JPanel frame = new JPanel();
    add(frame);
    pack();
    addKeyListener(this);
    repaint();
```

This answer is kinda unfinished but I'll look more into it and update this. Particularly, the JPanel is an element in the JFrame.

---

UPDATE: Here is a small working example. Use WASD to move the rectangle around the screen.

---

This is the JFrame.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private MyJPanel frame;

    public MyJFrame() {
        super();
        frame = new MyJPanel();
        add(frame);
        pack();
        addKeyListener(this);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJFrame window = new MyJFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Test");
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint() {
        super.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        frame.keyPressed(e);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

---

This is the JPanel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public MyJPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x,y,20,20);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        switch (k) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                x++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                x--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                y--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                y++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Super calls the constructor of the superclass. In this case, since it extends JFrame, it calls JFrame's constructor. By default, all constructors call their super constructors, but this makes it clearer and more obvious...

Comment: This helped a lot. big thanks! do you mind if I use your JFrame code? I'm onto a different approach though. I just need a guide how does override works super works. again, thanks :D

Comment: Sure, I'll put my code in a github repo and put it under the WTFPL license.

Comment: Hey @user3481750 my code is over [here](https://github.com/anubiann00b/JFrameExample) if you want to take a look at it. Shoot me a pull request if you want to change anything.